# How does one display straight quotes in the normal font?

Tags: symbols, xetex, punctuation

From this code:

```
\subsubsection{General Escaping Format}
Generally, escaping MUST be done in a manner similar to most programming
languages, such as C, C++, Java, or similar, for quoted string escapes. Such an
escaping scheme is defined by three characters: a starting delimiter, a
termination delimiter, and an escape character. For instance, in C, the starting
delimiter is the quote mark, ", the ending delimiter is also a quote
mark ", and the escape character is the backslash \textbackslash.
```

XeTeX gives this:

[image: LaTeX Output]

Note in particular the quotes that I want to be raw C style `"` characters, are converted into a pair of right curly quotes. Of course, I'm talking about programming languages in this section, so I need the quotes to be displayed as typewriter style straight quotes. I can force the straight quotes if I use `\verb`, but this causes the quotes to look strange because the actual font is different.

Comment: @AlanMunn: Ah, that does seem to be the problem. If I change the main font to something like Times New Roman it "just works". Why not make that an answer?

Comment: In theory you could change the verbatim font by redefining an internal macro. Also `\Verbdef\dblq{"}` and then `\dblq` (`newverbs` package) should do it, but Werners answer is much better anyway.

Comment: This _is_ code, you should use `\texttt` or `\verb` or `\lstinline` or … If you find the output weird, change your typewriter font.

Comment: @AndreyVihrov: Ah, that is a good point. Perhaps I should find a typewriter font that does not clash so violently with my main text. Now to find out how to define a user defined font...

Answer (score 8):

You can use `\textquotedbl` with

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fontenc
```

Here is a display of the output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fontenc
\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{3}\setcounter{subsection}{1}% Just for this example
\subsubsection{General Escaping Format}
Generally, escaping MUST be done in a manner similar to most programming
languages, such as C, C++, Java, or similar, for quoted string escapes. Such an
escaping scheme is defined by three characters: a starting delimiter, a
termination delimiter, and an escape character. For instance, in C, the starting
delimiter is the quote mark, \textquotedbl, the ending delimiter is also a quote
mark \textquotedbl, and the escape character is the backslash \textbackslash.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just my 2 cents concerning graphical design: the typewriter font is there to typeset pieces of code as well, isn't it? ... and since `"` and `<backslash>` are pieces of code in this case...

Comment: The question mentions XeTeX so T1-encoding is not a suitable encoding. With the EU1-encoding set by fontspec `\textquotedbl` will not work as the ligatures setting mentioned by Enrico will interfere.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is in the `Ligatures=TeX` option that is automatically added when you say only

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
```

so using the Latin Modern fonts. If you *redefine* the font without the option, then typing `"` will give straight quotes. So

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
```

If however you want to keep the other "traditional ligatures", you can make a copy of `text-tex.map`, call it `text-tex-sq.map` (for instance), and modify it to read as

```
; TECkit mapping for TeX input conventions <-> Unicode characters

LHSName "TeX-text"
RHSName "UNICODE"

pass(Unicode)

; ligatures from Knuth's original CMR fonts
U+002D U+002D                   <>      U+2013  ; -- -> en dash
U+002D U+002D U+002D    <>      U+2014  ; --- -> em dash

U+0027                  <>      U+2019  ; ' -> right single quote
U+0027 U+0027   <>      U+201D  ; '' -> right double quote
;U+0022                   >      U+201D  ; " -> right double quote ; no change!

U+0060                  <>      U+2018  ; ` -> left single quote
U+0060 U+0060   <>      U+201C  ; `` -> left double quote

U+0021 U+0060   <>      U+00A1  ; !` -> inverted exclam
U+003F U+0060   <>      U+00BF  ; ?` -> inverted question

; additions supported in T1 encoding
U+002C U+002C   <>      U+201E  ; ,, -> DOUBLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK
U+003C U+003C   <>      U+00AB  ; << -> LEFT POINTING GUILLEMET
U+003E U+003E   <>      U+00BB  ; >> -> RIGHT POINTING GUILLEMET
```

Compile with `teckit_compile tex-text-sq.map` and keep the `text-text-sq.tec` file that will be produced in the same directory as your file: now the call

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text-sq]{Latin Modern Roman}
```

will give the "traditional ligatures" but keep straight double quotes straight.

Comment: I personally would remove all ligatures with the exception of `--` and `---`. Actually I think it would be a good idea if there would exist a fontspec option "Ligatures=onlydashes".

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Legacy documents use the traditional ligatures. I would drop `U+0022 > U+201D` altogether from `tex-text.map`: the fact that `"` produced a closing double quote is only an artifact of history (and only in OT1 encoding).

Answer (score 0):

Immediately reset font features after loading fontspec.

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily,\sffamily,\ttfamily]{}
```